# Stop frontend fetch request from stopping me redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using node and express developing a small app where I click a share button on the frontend to send an array to the backend, where I then save to a database and create a share token which I can then use to get that array method from the database. It does indeed save in the database, but doesn't redirect after and can't get it to.

Frontend:

```js
document.querySelector('#share').addEventListener('click', (e) =>{


  fetch('/',{
    method:'POST', 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({favourites})
  
  })
  .catch(err=> {
    console.log(err)
  })

});
```

Backend:

```js
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  jsonFavs = req.body


  function isEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
  }

  if (!isEmpty(jsonFavs)){
    crypto.randomBytes(6, (err, buffer)=>{
      const token = buffer.toString('hex')


      const favArray = new favDataModel({
        favs: jsonFavs,
        shareCode: token
      }) 

      return favArray.save()
      .then(result => {
        return res.status(301).redirect('index', {
          pageTitle: 'Movie Favourites',
          path: `/${token}`,
          favourites: []

        })
      })

      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })


    })
  }

});
```

The problem is I can't do the needed redirect after the fetch request from the frontend. I've tried several suggestions from somewhat related problems but still can't figure it out.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Thanks I believe you edited it to correctly format it? In the future I will follow proper formatting [instructions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks#:~:text=Use%20the%20%7B%7D%20button%20above,%E2%8C%98%20K%20on%20OS%20X) thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if your backend returns the new path in a 201/Created status:

```js
res.status(201).json({ path: `/${token}`})
```

And then your frontend reads that and does the redirect:

```js
fetch("/", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ favourites }),
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    window.location.href = data.path;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks alot for that perspective, that did work!